# Dynamically get the field type while reading a row from a database table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am reading rows from a table in SQL Server using C# in SSIS. As I loop through each column I want to get the datatype of the field from the table. Here is my code:

```
string s = "";

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\cassf\Documents\Tyler Tech\FL\ncc3\CM_Property.csv", true))
        {            
            foreach (PropertyInfo inputColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!inputColumn.Name.EndsWith("IsNull"))
                {
                try
                {
                    s += Convert.ToString(inputColumn.GetValue(Row,null).ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    some code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First issue is when I do the `Convert.ToString()` on a Bit field from the database, it changes the value to either `True` or `False`.  I want the actual value of `1` or `0`.

So to try and fix this I want to check the field type for `Boolean`, it appears that the script is converting from a bit to `boolean`.  Then I can manually put the `1` or `0` back.  I would prefer to have the value directly from the database though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: Cast the bool to an int...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd implement a helper function to make your own conversion, when needed, like this:

```
string s = "";

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\cassf\Documents\Tyler Tech\FL\ncc3\CM_Property.csv", true))
        {            
            foreach (PropertyInfo inputColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!inputColumn.Name.EndsWith("IsNull"))
                {
                try
                {
                    s += ValueToString(inputColumn.GetValue(Row,null));
                }
                catch
                {
                    some code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

protected string ValueToString(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("I don't know how to convert null to string, implement me!");
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(value.GetType()))
    {
        // Any kind of special treatment, you implement here...
        case TypeCode.Boolean: return Convert.ToInt16(value).ToString();
        default: return value.ToString(); // ...otherwise, just use the common conversion
    }
}
```

For booleans, you just convert it to Int, and the int to string (you'll get 1 or 0 in string format).

Depending on what you're going to do with the `s` variable, you might want to surround string values with quotes, if so, you could do it inside `ValueToString()` method.

Comment: How do you do the int cast and then string cast?  I haven'e has succcess yet.

Comment: @Cass look my example code, specifically the `ValueToString()` method. I receive any value as parameter (it could be a string, int, double, boolean), then I test its type using the `switch`. If its type code is boolean, I convert the value to int using the `Convert.ToInt16(value)`, then to string using `ToString()`. Did you try using my example code? I've been using it in a project for a couple of years.

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you very much! Forgot to mark this as answered.

Comment: @Cass you're welcome, I'm glad to help. No problem at all, you could mark my answer as accepted.